# Horizontally center content on small screens

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm using css grid to style footer. On bigger screens it looks fine, but on smaller content
is not centered horizontally. Can you spot my mistake, or should i use flex instead or some other approach?

```css
footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, min-content);
  justify-content: center;
  gap: .5em;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

footer a {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

footer a:hover {
  fill: orange;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

footer img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

footer img:hover {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

@media (max-width: 682px) {
  footer {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content);
  }
  
  footer a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  
  footer img {
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <a
          class="linked__in"
          href="#"
        >
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="M19 0h-14c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.239 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5zm-11 19h-3v-11h3v11zm-1.5-12.268c-.966 0-1.75-.79-1.75-1.764s.784-1.764 1.75-1.764 1.75.79 1.75 1.764-.783 1.764-1.75 1.764zm13.5 12.268h-3v-5.604c0-3.368-4-3.113-4 0v5.604h-3v-11h3v1.765c1.396-2.586 7-2.777 7 2.476v6.759z"
            />
          </svg>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="gh">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 128 128">
            <path
              d="M64 1.512c-23.493 0-42.545 19.047-42.545 42.545 0 18.797 12.19 34.745 29.095 40.37 2.126.394 2.907-.923 2.907-2.047 0-1.014-.04-4.366-.058-7.92-11.837 2.573-14.334-5.02-14.334-5.02-1.935-4.918-4.724-6.226-4.724-6.226-3.86-2.64.29-2.586.29-2.586 4.273.3 6.523 4.385 6.523 4.385 3.794 6.504 9.953 4.623 12.38 3.536.383-2.75 1.485-4.628 2.702-5.69-9.45-1.075-19.384-4.724-19.384-21.026 0-4.645 1.662-8.44 4.384-11.42-.442-1.072-1.898-5.4.412-11.26 0 0 3.572-1.142 11.7 4.363 3.395-.943 7.035-1.416 10.65-1.432 3.616.017 7.258.49 10.658 1.432 8.12-5.504 11.688-4.362 11.688-4.362 2.316 5.86.86 10.187.418 11.26 2.728 2.978 4.378 6.774 4.378 11.42 0 16.34-9.953 19.938-19.427 20.99 1.526 1.32 2.886 3.91 2.886 7.88 0 5.692-.048 10.273-.048 11.674 0 1.13.766 2.458 2.922 2.04 16.896-5.632 29.07-21.574 29.07-40.365C106.545 20.56 87.497 1.512 64 1.512z"
              clip-rule="evenodd"
            />
            <path
              d="M37.57 62.596c-.095.212-.428.275-.73.13-.31-.14-.482-.427-.382-.64.09-.216.424-.277.733-.132.31.14.486.43.38.642zm-.524-.388M39.293 64.52c-.203.187-.6.1-.87-.198-.278-.297-.33-.694-.124-.884.208-.188.593-.1.87.197.28.3.335.693.123.884zm-.406-.437M40.97 66.968c-.26.182-.687.012-.95-.367-.262-.377-.262-.83.005-1.013.264-.182.684-.018.95.357.262.385.262.84-.005 1.024zm0 0M43.268 69.336c-.233.257-.73.188-1.093-.163-.372-.343-.475-.83-.242-1.087.237-.257.736-.185 1.102.163.37.342.482.83.233 1.086zm0 0M46.44 70.71c-.104.334-.582.485-1.064.344-.482-.146-.796-.536-.7-.872.1-.336.582-.493 1.067-.342.48.144.795.53.696.87zm0 0M49.92 70.965c.013.35-.396.642-.902.648-.508.012-.92-.272-.926-.618 0-.354.4-.642.908-.65.506-.01.92.272.92.62zm0 0M53.16 70.414c.06.342-.29.694-.793.787-.494.092-.95-.12-1.014-.46-.06-.35.297-.7.79-.792.503-.088.953.118 1.017.466zm0 0"
            />
            <path
              fill="#100E0F"
              d="M24.855 108.302h-10.7a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v5.232a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.173v6.5s-.937.32-3.53.32c-3.056 0-7.327-1.116-7.327-10.508 0-9.393 4.448-10.63 8.624-10.63 3.614 0 5.17.636 6.162.943.31.094.6-.216.6-.492l1.193-5.055a.468.468 0 0 0-.192-.39c-.403-.288-2.857-1.66-9.058-1.66-7.144 0-14.472 3.038-14.472 17.65 0 14.61 8.39 16.787 15.46 16.787 5.854 0 9.405-2.502 9.405-2.502.146-.08.162-.285.162-.38v-16.316a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zM79.506 94.81H73.48a.5.5 0 0 0-.498.503l.002 11.644h-9.392V95.313a.5.5 0 0 0-.497-.503H57.07a.5.5 0 0 0-.498.503v31.53c0 .277.224.503.498.503h6.025a.5.5 0 0 0 .497-.504v-13.486h9.392l-.016 13.486c0 .278.224.504.5.504h6.038a.5.5 0 0 0 .497-.504v-31.53c0-.278-.22-.502-.497-.502zM32.34 95.527c-2.144 0-3.884 1.753-3.884 3.923 0 2.167 1.74 3.925 3.884 3.925 2.146 0 3.885-1.758 3.885-3.925 0-2.17-1.74-3.923-3.885-3.923zM35.296 105.135H29.29c-.276 0-.522.284-.522.56v20.852c0 .613.382.795.876.795h5.41c.595 0 .74-.292.74-.805v-6.346-14.553a.5.5 0 0 0-.498-.502zM102.902 105.182h-5.98a.5.5 0 0 0-.496.504v15.46s-1.52 1.11-3.675 1.11-2.727-.977-2.727-3.088v-13.482a.5.5 0 0 0-.497-.504h-6.068a.502.502 0 0 0-.498.504v14.502c0 6.27 3.495 7.804 8.302 7.804 3.944 0 7.124-2.18 7.124-2.18s.15 1.15.22 1.285c.07.136.247.273.44.273l3.86-.017a.502.502 0 0 0 .5-.504l-.003-21.166a.504.504 0 0 0-.5-.502zM119.244 104.474c-3.396 0-5.706 1.515-5.706 1.515V95.312a.5.5 0 0 0-.497-.503H107a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.503v31.53a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.503h4.192c.19 0 .332-.097.437-.268.103-.17.254-1.454.254-1.454s2.47 2.34 7.148 2.34c5.49 0 8.64-2.784 8.64-12.502s-5.03-10.988-8.428-10.988zm-2.36 17.764c-2.073-.063-3.48-1.004-3.48-1.004v-9.985s1.388-.85 3.09-1.004c2.153-.193 4.228.458 4.228 5.594 0 5.417-.935 6.486-3.837 6.398zM53.195 122.12c-.263 0-.937.107-1.63.107-2.22 0-2.973-1.032-2.973-2.368v-8.866h4.52a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.504v-4.856a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.502h-4.52l-.007-5.97c0-.227-.116-.34-.378-.34h-6.16c-.238 0-.367.106-.367.335v6.17s-3.087.745-3.295.805a.5.5 0 0 0-.36.48v3.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .497.503h3.158v9.328c0 6.93 4.86 7.61 8.14 7.61 1.497 0 3.29-.48 3.586-.59.18-.067.283-.252.283-.453l.004-4.265a.51.51 0 0 0-.5-.502z"
            />
          </svg>
        </a>


         <img
            src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/11989189.png?theme=dark"
            width="208"
            height="58"
            class="so"
            alt="profile for Nikola Pavicevic at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers"
            title="profile for Nikola Pavicevic at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers"
         />
        <a class="mail__me" href="#">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
            <polygon id="XMLID_869_" points="0,127.5 0,274.219 104.8,206.1  " />
            <polygon
              id="XMLID_870_"
              points="400,274.219 400,127.5 295.2,206.1     "
            />
            <polygon
              id="XMLID_871_"
              points="200,277.5 130.357,225.268 0,310 0,340 400,340 400,310 269.643,225.268     "
            />
            <polygon
              id="XMLID_872_"
              points="0,90 200,240 400,90 400,60 0,60   "
            />
          </svg>
        </a>
      </footer>
```

Comment: Why do you want show items horizontally in small screen!? Isn't better to show them vertically?

Comment: Kinda is showed vertically, in 2 rows, i will only like to center it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for help.
Problem was with so flair image (some invisible margins) so i managed to correct that with positioning.

```css
footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, min-content);
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

footer a {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

@media (max-width: 682px) {
  footer {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  }
  
  footer a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  footer .so {
    position: relative;
    left: -2em;
    top: -.2em;
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
  footer .so:hover {
    transform: scale(0.65);
  }
}

.linked__in {
  justify-self: left; 
} 


footer a:hover {
  fill: var(--orange);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

footer img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  border-radius: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

footer img:hover {
  border: 3px solid var(--orange);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <a
          class="linked__in"
          href="#"
        >
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="M19 0h-14c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.239 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5zm-11 19h-3v-11h3v11zm-1.5-12.268c-.966 0-1.75-.79-1.75-1.764s.784-1.764 1.75-1.764 1.75.79 1.75 1.764-.783 1.764-1.75 1.764zm13.5 12.268h-3v-5.604c0-3.368-4-3.113-4 0v5.604h-3v-11h3v1.765c1.396-2.586 7-2.777 7 2.476v6.759z"
            />
          </svg>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="gh">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 128 128">
            <path
              d="M64 1.512c-23.493 0-42.545 19.047-42.545 42.545 0 18.797 12.19 34.745 29.095 40.37 2.126.394 2.907-.923 2.907-2.047 0-1.014-.04-4.366-.058-7.92-11.837 2.573-14.334-5.02-14.334-5.02-1.935-4.918-4.724-6.226-4.724-6.226-3.86-2.64.29-2.586.29-2.586 4.273.3 6.523 4.385 6.523 4.385 3.794 6.504 9.953 4.623 12.38 3.536.383-2.75 1.485-4.628 2.702-5.69-9.45-1.075-19.384-4.724-19.384-21.026 0-4.645 1.662-8.44 4.384-11.42-.442-1.072-1.898-5.4.412-11.26 0 0 3.572-1.142 11.7 4.363 3.395-.943 7.035-1.416 10.65-1.432 3.616.017 7.258.49 10.658 1.432 8.12-5.504 11.688-4.362 11.688-4.362 2.316 5.86.86 10.187.418 11.26 2.728 2.978 4.378 6.774 4.378 11.42 0 16.34-9.953 19.938-19.427 20.99 1.526 1.32 2.886 3.91 2.886 7.88 0 5.692-.048 10.273-.048 11.674 0 1.13.766 2.458 2.922 2.04 16.896-5.632 29.07-21.574 29.07-40.365C106.545 20.56 87.497 1.512 64 1.512z"
              clip-rule="evenodd"
            />
            <path
              d="M37.57 62.596c-.095.212-.428.275-.73.13-.31-.14-.482-.427-.382-.64.09-.216.424-.277.733-.132.31.14.486.43.38.642zm-.524-.388M39.293 64.52c-.203.187-.6.1-.87-.198-.278-.297-.33-.694-.124-.884.208-.188.593-.1.87.197.28.3.335.693.123.884zm-.406-.437M40.97 66.968c-.26.182-.687.012-.95-.367-.262-.377-.262-.83.005-1.013.264-.182.684-.018.95.357.262.385.262.84-.005 1.024zm0 0M43.268 69.336c-.233.257-.73.188-1.093-.163-.372-.343-.475-.83-.242-1.087.237-.257.736-.185 1.102.163.37.342.482.83.233 1.086zm0 0M46.44 70.71c-.104.334-.582.485-1.064.344-.482-.146-.796-.536-.7-.872.1-.336.582-.493 1.067-.342.48.144.795.53.696.87zm0 0M49.92 70.965c.013.35-.396.642-.902.648-.508.012-.92-.272-.926-.618 0-.354.4-.642.908-.65.506-.01.92.272.92.62zm0 0M53.16 70.414c.06.342-.29.694-.793.787-.494.092-.95-.12-1.014-.46-.06-.35.297-.7.79-.792.503-.088.953.118 1.017.466zm0 0"
            />
            <path
              fill="#100E0F"
              d="M24.855 108.302h-10.7a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v5.232a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.173v6.5s-.937.32-3.53.32c-3.056 0-7.327-1.116-7.327-10.508 0-9.393 4.448-10.63 8.624-10.63 3.614 0 5.17.636 6.162.943.31.094.6-.216.6-.492l1.193-5.055a.468.468 0 0 0-.192-.39c-.403-.288-2.857-1.66-9.058-1.66-7.144 0-14.472 3.038-14.472 17.65 0 14.61 8.39 16.787 15.46 16.787 5.854 0 9.405-2.502 9.405-2.502.146-.08.162-.285.162-.38v-16.316a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zM79.506 94.81H73.48a.5.5 0 0 0-.498.503l.002 11.644h-9.392V95.313a.5.5 0 0 0-.497-.503H57.07a.5.5 0 0 0-.498.503v31.53c0 .277.224.503.498.503h6.025a.5.5 0 0 0 .497-.504v-13.486h9.392l-.016 13.486c0 .278.224.504.5.504h6.038a.5.5 0 0 0 .497-.504v-31.53c0-.278-.22-.502-.497-.502zM32.34 95.527c-2.144 0-3.884 1.753-3.884 3.923 0 2.167 1.74 3.925 3.884 3.925 2.146 0 3.885-1.758 3.885-3.925 0-2.17-1.74-3.923-3.885-3.923zM35.296 105.135H29.29c-.276 0-.522.284-.522.56v20.852c0 .613.382.795.876.795h5.41c.595 0 .74-.292.74-.805v-6.346-14.553a.5.5 0 0 0-.498-.502zM102.902 105.182h-5.98a.5.5 0 0 0-.496.504v15.46s-1.52 1.11-3.675 1.11-2.727-.977-2.727-3.088v-13.482a.5.5 0 0 0-.497-.504h-6.068a.502.502 0 0 0-.498.504v14.502c0 6.27 3.495 7.804 8.302 7.804 3.944 0 7.124-2.18 7.124-2.18s.15 1.15.22 1.285c.07.136.247.273.44.273l3.86-.017a.502.502 0 0 0 .5-.504l-.003-21.166a.504.504 0 0 0-.5-.502zM119.244 104.474c-3.396 0-5.706 1.515-5.706 1.515V95.312a.5.5 0 0 0-.497-.503H107a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.503v31.53a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.503h4.192c.19 0 .332-.097.437-.268.103-.17.254-1.454.254-1.454s2.47 2.34 7.148 2.34c5.49 0 8.64-2.784 8.64-12.502s-5.03-10.988-8.428-10.988zm-2.36 17.764c-2.073-.063-3.48-1.004-3.48-1.004v-9.985s1.388-.85 3.09-1.004c2.153-.193 4.228.458 4.228 5.594 0 5.417-.935 6.486-3.837 6.398zM53.195 122.12c-.263 0-.937.107-1.63.107-2.22 0-2.973-1.032-2.973-2.368v-8.866h4.52a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.504v-4.856a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.502h-4.52l-.007-5.97c0-.227-.116-.34-.378-.34h-6.16c-.238 0-.367.106-.367.335v6.17s-3.087.745-3.295.805a.5.5 0 0 0-.36.48v3.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .497.503h3.158v9.328c0 6.93 4.86 7.61 8.14 7.61 1.497 0 3.29-.48 3.586-.59.18-.067.283-.252.283-.453l.004-4.265a.51.51 0 0 0-.5-.502z"
            />
          </svg>
        </a>


         <img
            src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/11989189.png?theme=dark"
            width="208"
            height="58"
            class="so"
            alt="profile for Nikola Pavicevic at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers"
            title="profile for Nikola Pavicevic at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers"
         />
        <a class="mail__me" href="#">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
            <polygon id="XMLID_869_" points="0,127.5 0,274.219 104.8,206.1  " />
            <polygon
              id="XMLID_870_"
              points="400,274.219 400,127.5 295.2,206.1     "
            />
            <polygon
              id="XMLID_871_"
              points="200,277.5 130.357,225.268 0,310 0,340 400,340 400,310 269.643,225.268     "
            />
            <polygon
              id="XMLID_872_"
              points="0,90 200,240 400,90 400,60 0,60   "
            />
          </svg>
        </a>
      </footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use flex and instead of

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

footer div {
  min-width: 70px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

footer div a {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

footer div a:hover {
  fill: orange;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

footer div img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

footer div img:hover {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

@media (max-width: 682px) {
  footer {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  footer div {
   margin: 0;
    width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <a class="linked__in" href="#">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="M19 0h-14c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.239 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5zm-11 19h-3v-11h3v11zm-1.5-12.268c-.966 0-1.75-.79-1.75-1.764s.784-1.764 1.75-1.764 1.75.79 1.75 1.764-.783 1.764-1.75 1.764zm13.5 12.268h-3v-5.604c0-3.368-4-3.113-4 0v5.604h-3v-11h3v1.765c1.396-2.586 7-2.777 7 2.476v6.759z"
            />
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="gh">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 128 128">
            <path
              d="M64 1.512c-23.493 0-42.545 19.047-42.545 42.545 0 18.797 12.19 34.745 29.095 40.37 2.126.394 2.907-.923 2.907-2.047 0-1.014-.04-4.366-.058-7.92-11.837 2.573-14.334-5.02-14.334-5.02-1.935-4.918-4.724-6.226-4.724-6.226-3.86-2.64.29-2.586.29-2.586 4.273.3 6.523 4.385 6.523 4.385 3.794 6.504 9.953 4.623 12.38 3.536.383-2.75 1.485-4.628 2.702-5.69-9.45-1.075-19.384-4.724-19.384-21.026 0-4.645 1.662-8.44 4.384-11.42-.442-1.072-1.898-5.4.412-11.26 0 0 3.572-1.142 11.7 4.363 3.395-.943 7.035-1.416 10.65-1.432 3.616.017 7.258.49 10.658 1.432 8.12-5.504 11.688-4.362 11.688-4.362 2.316 5.86.86 10.187.418 11.26 2.728 2.978 4.378 6.774 4.378 11.42 0 16.34-9.953 19.938-19.427 20.99 1.526 1.32 2.886 3.91 2.886 7.88 0 5.692-.048 10.273-.048 11.674 0 1.13.766 2.458 2.922 2.04 16.896-5.632 29.07-21.574 29.07-40.365C106.545 20.56 87.497 1.512 64 1.512z"
              clip-rule="evenodd"
            />
            <path
              d="M37.57 62.596c-.095.212-.428.275-.73.13-.31-.14-.482-.427-.382-.64.09-.216.424-.277.733-.132.31.14.486.43.38.642zm-.524-.388M39.293 64.52c-.203.187-.6.1-.87-.198-.278-.297-.33-.694-.124-.884.208-.188.593-.1.87.197.28.3.335.693.123.884zm-.406-.437M40.97 66.968c-.26.182-.687.012-.95-.367-.262-.377-.262-.83.005-1.013.264-.182.684-.018.95.357.262.385.262.84-.005 1.024zm0 0M43.268 69.336c-.233.257-.73.188-1.093-.163-.372-.343-.475-.83-.242-1.087.237-.257.736-.185 1.102.163.37.342.482.83.233 1.086zm0 0M46.44 70.71c-.104.334-.582.485-1.064.344-.482-.146-.796-.536-.7-.872.1-.336.582-.493 1.067-.342.48.144.795.53.696.87zm0 0M49.92 70.965c.013.35-.396.642-.902.648-.508.012-.92-.272-.926-.618 0-.354.4-.642.908-.65.506-.01.92.272.92.62zm0 0M53.16 70.414c.06.342-.29.694-.793.787-.494.092-.95-.12-1.014-.46-.06-.35.297-.7.79-.792.503-.088.953.118 1.017.466zm0 0"
            />
            <path
              fill="#100E0F"
              d="M24.855 108.302h-10.7a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v5.232a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.173v6.5s-.937.32-3.53.32c-3.056 0-7.327-1.116-7.327-10.508 0-9.393 4.448-10.63 8.624-10.63 3.614 0 5.17.636 6.162.943.31.094.6-.216.6-.492l1.193-5.055a.468.468 0 0 0-.192-.39c-.403-.288-2.857-1.66-9.058-1.66-7.144 0-14.472 3.038-14.472 17.65 0 14.61 8.39 16.787 15.46 16.787 5.854 0 9.405-2.502 9.405-2.502.146-.08.162-.285.162-.38v-16.316a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zM79.506 94.81H73.48a.5.5 0 0 0-.498.503l.002 11.644h-9.392V95.313a.5.5 0 0 0-.497-.503H57.07a.5.5 0 0 0-.498.503v31.53c0 .277.224.503.498.503h6.025a.5.5 0 0 0 .497-.504v-13.486h9.392l-.016 13.486c0 .278.224.504.5.504h6.038a.5.5 0 0 0 .497-.504v-31.53c0-.278-.22-.502-.497-.502zM32.34 95.527c-2.144 0-3.884 1.753-3.884 3.923 0 2.167 1.74 3.925 3.884 3.925 2.146 0 3.885-1.758 3.885-3.925 0-2.17-1.74-3.923-3.885-3.923zM35.296 105.135H29.29c-.276 0-.522.284-.522.56v20.852c0 .613.382.795.876.795h5.41c.595 0 .74-.292.74-.805v-6.346-14.553a.5.5 0 0 0-.498-.502zM102.902 105.182h-5.98a.5.5 0 0 0-.496.504v15.46s-1.52 1.11-3.675 1.11-2.727-.977-2.727-3.088v-13.482a.5.5 0 0 0-.497-.504h-6.068a.502.502 0 0 0-.498.504v14.502c0 6.27 3.495 7.804 8.302 7.804 3.944 0 7.124-2.18 7.124-2.18s.15 1.15.22 1.285c.07.136.247.273.44.273l3.86-.017a.502.502 0 0 0 .5-.504l-.003-21.166a.504.504 0 0 0-.5-.502zM119.244 104.474c-3.396 0-5.706 1.515-5.706 1.515V95.312a.5.5 0 0 0-.497-.503H107a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.503v31.53a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.503h4.192c.19 0 .332-.097.437-.268.103-.17.254-1.454.254-1.454s2.47 2.34 7.148 2.34c5.49 0 8.64-2.784 8.64-12.502s-5.03-10.988-8.428-10.988zm-2.36 17.764c-2.073-.063-3.48-1.004-3.48-1.004v-9.985s1.388-.85 3.09-1.004c2.153-.193 4.228.458 4.228 5.594 0 5.417-.935 6.486-3.837 6.398zM53.195 122.12c-.263 0-.937.107-1.63.107-2.22 0-2.973-1.032-2.973-2.368v-8.866h4.52a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.504v-4.856a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.502h-4.52l-.007-5.97c0-.227-.116-.34-.378-.34h-6.16c-.238 0-.367.106-.367.335v6.17s-3.087.745-3.295.805a.5.5 0 0 0-.36.48v3.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .497.503h3.158v9.328c0 6.93 4.86 7.61 8.14 7.61 1.497 0 3.29-.48 3.586-.59.18-.067.283-.252.283-.453l.004-4.265a.51.51 0 0 0-.5-.502z"
            />
          </svg>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/11989189.png?theme=dark" width="208" height="58" class="so" alt="profile for Nikola Pavicevic at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for Nikola Pavicevic at Stack Overflow, Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers"
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="mail__me" href="#">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
            <polygon id="XMLID_869_" points="0,127.5 0,274.219 104.8,206.1  " />
            <polygon
              id="XMLID_870_"
              points="400,274.219 400,127.5 295.2,206.1     "
            />
            <polygon
              id="XMLID_871_"
              points="200,277.5 130.357,225.268 0,310 0,340 400,340 400,310 269.643,225.268     "
            />
            <polygon
              id="XMLID_872_"
              points="0,90 200,240 400,90 400,60 0,60   "
            />
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's nice, but i wanted 2 columns in smaller screens, stubborn me :)

Comment: I have updated the answer, I hope it would be what you want.

Comment: Yesss that's it, thanks again mate, enjoy in beautiful day :)

Comment: You have removed the confirmation, isn't it the correct answer?

Comment: Sorry mate, it is correct, but not for my case :( flair image is making problems, you can look at my answer, cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe the value you put into the repeat() of your grid-template-columns make it not horizontally in some cases. I don't even know if your 'min-content' here is a thing in CSS Grid. I've already seen min-content and max-content in a minmax parenthesis but not in a repeat parenthesis (as you can see in this documentation : [mdn doc about grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) ),

Personally, I always use this class :

```
    .grid-columns {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);
    gap: 0.5em;
}
```

The `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);` is the "most useful" line as it allows you, in your div, to put as much children as you want and the width they will take will be automatically resized.
The margin and gap are optional, very personnal.

Another solution could be to use the [place-items property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/place-items) to center content in both axis.

Comment: Thanks mate, great info , didn't know about `place-items`, but `repeat(auto-fit, 1fr)` doesn't do what i wanted (in firefox i got invalid-value), any ways thanks a lot, i learned new things from your answer  , cheers :)

Comment: No problem ! :)
I'm pretty much inspired by Kevin Powell's channel on Youtube, a front-end dev that has a lot of skills into teaching niche CSS properties, if you want to give it a look. It helped me a lot.